# Do bubble/vacuum diagrams have some physical implication?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, observables

While calculating S-matrix elements $$\langle\Omega|T \{ \phi(x_1)...\phi(x_n) \}|\Omega\rangle=\frac{\langle0|T \Big\{ \phi_0(x_1)...\phi_0(x_n) e^{i\int d^4x\mathcal{L}_{i}[\phi_0]}\Big\}|0\rangle}{\langle0|T \Big\{e^{i\int d^4x\mathcal{L}_{i}[\phi_0]} \Big\}|0\rangle}$$

Bubble diagrams come from the numerator when doing wick contraction but they get canceled due to the same contributing terms with opposite sign from the denominator. Since S-matrix element (RHS) is the observables here so does it mean that bubble diagrams don't carry any physical implication, since in LHS they cancel each other hence no contribution in something observable?

Same idea is conveyed when we're told to use only connected diagrams while calculating S-matrix elements.

Comment: They don't contribute to the S matrix, but bubble diagrams will contribute to the ground state energy for example.

Comment: @SethWhitsitt I have come across this property only orally/informally; never seen an explicit calculation so I will be indebted to you if you can provide me a reference to actual calculation of ground state energy using bubble diagrams.

Comment: I believe the classic reference is Symanzik: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/055032138190482X?via%3Dihub The whole paper is rather difficult to read in my opinion, but equation (4.1) is essentially the statement you need if you know how to interpret the right-hand side as the set of connected bubble diagrams. There is also an explicit discussion of bubble diagrams in Kleinert's book "Critical properties of $\phi^4$ theories." The focus of that book is really statistical field theory, but there is a relation to quantum field theory after Wick rotation.